# Convert string field to ObjectId, Error: Unsupported conversion from object to objectId in $convert with no onError value

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have some fields in some of my documents which should be ObjectId, but the are string.

So i need a mongo script to convert all this string fields to ObjectId.

My collection:

```
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5dcaafcaeaec3701a2774d48"),

    "cover_id": ObjectId("5dcaafcceaec3701a2774d4b")
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5dcaafe2eaec3701a2774d72"),

    "cover_id": "5dcaafcfeaec3701a2774d51"
  }
]
```

My current mongo script is:

```
var bulk = db.product2.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();

bulk.find({}).update([
    {
        $set: {
            cover_id: {
                $cond: {
                    if: {  $type: "string" } ,
                    then: {$convert: { input: "$cover_id", to: "objectId" }},
                    else: "$a"
                }
            }
        }
    }
]);

bulk.execute();
```

but i'm facing this error:

> "code" : 241, "errmsg" : "Unsupported conversion from object to objectId in $convert with no onError value"

Comment: The error is in this code bit: `{  $type: "string" } `. See the [$type](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/type/index.html) usage.

Comment: Thanks . I corrected it to `if: { $eq: [ {$type: "$cover_id"}, "string" ] }`